# Talend - How to loop over an output from tmap

Tags: talend

I have a requirement were I am getting ***min_age*** and ***max_age*** from tmap. I want to loop over these 2 inputs i.e. from ***min_age*** to ***max_age*** and insert records into cassandra table per iteration value.

For example - **min_age** is 10 and **max_age** is 15, then I want to insert records as 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 and 15 in cassandra table.

I tried figuring out a solution but could not succeed. tloop component seemed to be the best fit but unfortunately tmap does not have an iterator connector.

Can anyone help out here.

Comment: If there is no iterator connector, you might want to use `tFlowToIterate`.

Answer (score 3):

You could just use tFlowToIterate to convert your input flow row into an iteration. Then add a loop on each iterated row to further iterate on the min/max values.  Then you can convert your iteration back to a flow using tIteratetoFlow.

Here is a test job:

[image]

This is how I set up my tRowGenerator to try and simulate your input flow (you can use more than one row if you want):

[image]

And the component settings for your loop:

[image]

And the component settings to convert your iteration back to a flow:

[image]

And this is the log output:

```
Starting job testjob at 11:35 19/06/2017.

[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3914
[statistics] connected
10
11
12
13
14
15
[statistics] disconnected
Job testjob ended at 11:35 19/06/2017. [exit code=0]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could have a subjob like this : `[inputflow] --> tFlowToIterate-->tLoop-->tFixedFlowInput--> DBInsert`

In tLoop, just use globalMap variables constructed by tFlowToIterate to populate your "from" and "to" fields (use ctrl space in these fields to find the variables constructed by tFlowToIterate).
In tFixedFlow, you can construct your data to be inserted : it is the current value of your tloop  : `((Integer)globalMap.get("tLoop_1_CURRENT_VALUE"))`